# Minimize the number of points in a piecewise linear approximation

Tags: optimization, algorithms, approximation, regression, machine-learning

I have $m$ data points $(x_i,y_i)$ in a given interval. I would like to find a **piecewise** linear function $f(x)$ that approximate these $m$ points with a minimum number of points $n$ so that my approximation error is below a tolerance $\epsilon$.

My $m$ points:
[image: points]

The function $f$ is a piecewise linear function defined with $n$ points $(x_a^{i},y_a^{i})$. For $n=4$, it would look like:

[image: approximation]

Approximation error:

$$\frac{1}{m} \sum_{1\le i\le m}(y_i-f(x_i))^2 \leq\epsilon$$

To solve that problem I need to find, for a given $n$, a way to obtain the optimal set of points $(x_a^{i},y_a^{i})$. I can try to minimize my approximation error with gradient descent, but the function is non-convex, so it might not converge to the global optimum.

If I solve the previous step, I can simply simply run the algorithm from $n=1,2,3,...$ and stop when my approximation error drops below $\epsilon$

I sounds like a rather common problem that perhaps already has a solution. Do you know of one, or can you propose an approach to that problem?

Comment: The [Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) can be used to find an approximation such that $\max_i(y_i-f(x_i))\le\epsilon$ instead.

Comment: To deal with $\sum_i (y_i-f(x_i))^2$ instead, you could consider a complete graph on vertices $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$; assign each edge $(i,j)$ a cost $w_{ij}=\sum_{i<k<j} (y_k-f_{ij}(x_k))^2$, where $f_{ij}$ is the linear approximation between $(x_i,y_i)$ and $(x_j,k_j)$; then find the shortest path from $1$ to $m$ using only $n-1$ edges.

Comment: @Rahul, Thanks! I think the Douglas-Peucker algorithm might actually be a suitable solution to my problem. I also like very much your graph-based approach for the squared error. Note that in both approaches one drawback is that the $(x_a^{i},y_a^{i})$ are picked among the $(x_{i},y_{i})$, which might not be optimal. I am also thinking that I could use the Douglas-Peucker solution to initialize a gradient descent algorithm much closer to the global optimum...

Comment: Seems to me that Douglas-Peucker, by fitting to certain input points exactly, fails to find better solutions that miss all points (as in OP's illustration).

Comment: this can be phrased as a mixed integer optimization problem, which can be solved for limited $n$

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the problem in the following way.

Take the interval  containing the first three points. Compute the correlation coefficient $\rho$.
 - if $\rho$ is not good enough, take just the first two points , mark them as to be in the 1st interval, and move to examine next three.
 - elif $\rho$ is quite good, add a fourth point  and recompute the coefficient; continue till $\rho$ remains good;
Repeat till partitioning all the points into contiguous intervals with good correlation.

You just have to consider what to do with the points at the border of the intervals :
 - you can keep the intervals disjointed;
 - or you can retake the last point into the computation of the correlation for the next, so overlapping the intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way that looks obvious to me; maybe someone wiser will point out how it's inefficient, or fails on perverse input.

Consider the $(a,b)$ plane in which each point represents a function $y=ax+b$.  Each of your inputs, with its tolerances, defines a band in that plane.  An intersection of such bands is a convex polygon.

So, starting at the left, pile on the constraints until this polygon vanishes, and then back up by one.  Your first line is represented by a point anywhere in this polygon; you may as well use its centroid, or the average of its corners.

Then do it again, starting with the last point "covered" by the first line.  Your $(x_a^2,y_a^2)$ is, of course, the intersection of the first two solution lines.

It could be interesting to see if starting from the right gives a different result.

(My aesthetic preference would be to use *all* maximal compatible subsequences, but it's not my question.)

Edit: This is the main idea of the following [paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/358746.358758) and is discussed [here](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Egodfried/student_projects/skang5_line_fitting/)

Comment: Can this concept be extended to piecewise polynomials of degree *n* with *k* continuous derivatives?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't simple because the piecewise linear function depends on the break points in a non differentiable way (it is however continuous). And thing get ugly if you varies the number of breaks.

It is much simpler to compute the best approximation for **fixed** breaks. Thus, a simple heuristic would be following:

1. Start with the linear best approximation $f_0$ on say $[a,b]$ (that is only two breaks). If the error is sufficiently small, stop.
2. Otherwise, add a break $c$ (for example in the middle) and compute the best approximation $f_1$. If the error is sufficiently small, stop.
3. Otherwise, compare the error of $f_1$ on $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$. Choose the subinterval with the larger error, say $[a,c]$, and add a new break in $[a,c]$. Compute the best approximation $f_2$. If the error is sufficiently small, stop.
4. Otherwise, ... and so on

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it converges to a minimum, but once I made a function to "convert" GPS points into a road.

To do so I took a rectangular region whose side is the double of the tolerance accumulating points as long as the rectangle could contain all of them. At this point I started with another rectangle containing at least the last point of the former rectangle.